# Repeating Javascript using Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am aware that Angular is used for generating HTML. Setting $scope.items to an array will cause  to generate multiple LI items.

In my case, for every element of items, I would like to invoke a Javascript function. The Javascript then adds somthing to the DOM.  is not allowed by Angular. What is the best way to invoke a javascript repeatedly using Angular?

Thanks,
Yash

Comment: This can be handled by a directive

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ng-init` directive wich will invoke custom function every `ng-repeat` iteration.

```
<li ng-repeat="member in members" ng-init="myFunc($index)">
    {{member.mId}}   
</li>
```

and in controller:

```
$scope.myFunc = function(index){
   console.log(index);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FuvRQ/1/

Comment: But this means a LI would also get created for every iteration. I want to ONLY call the javascript and not create an LI.

Comment: @Yash Then you don't need to use `ng-repeat` directive! Just use usual iterator (`for in` or `anggular.forEach`).

Answer (score 0):

best is to use a directive and perform your javascript function's functionality in

```
link:
```

and whatever you want to insert in the DOM can go as plain html in the property of directive

```
template:
```

read about directives these are one of the most powerful features of angular